# Surjective homomorphism from a finite group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G,G'$ are two groups and $\phi: G\rightarrow G'$ be a surjective homomorphism, Suppose $G$ is finite then show that $$|G|\text{ divides }|G'|$$.

N.B    I think this problem is wrong. As we can take the map $$\phi((x,y))=x$$ between the groups $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. This example contradicts the result mentioned in the question. Can somebody confirm if I am correct? As this problem came in a reputed university exam before.

Comment: Indeed the converse holds: $|G'|$ divides $|G|$. This can be proved by the first isomorphism theorem $G/ \ker \phi \cong G'$, so that $$|G|=|\ker \phi| \cdot |G'|$$

Comment: @Crostul sir please confirm whether my counterexample is correct?

Comment: Yes, your counterexample works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your counterexample is correct.
You can try to verify that $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism.
But clearly $|\Bbb{Z}_p\times \Bbb{Z}_p|=p^2$ clearly does not divide $|\Bbb{Z}_p|=p$.